# What is the best react router library to allow abstracting path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, angular-ui-router, react-navigation

I'm switching a project from AngularJS (with UI-Router) to ReactJS but I can't find a correct router from my application which allows simply to bastract routes.

I want to define the path only one time and access it simply. With UI-Router you call routes like "connected.home" but in most react routers you need the path every time like "/connected/home" but I want to change path easily if needed.

I found multiple libraries but no one seems to correct this problem.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here, as they solicit opinion-based answers.

Comment: https://github.com/ui-router/react

Comment: I prefer to use something else than UI Router, the goal is to use new technologies for react

Comment: Then what is it you are looking for? ui router for react does what you need.

Comment: UI Router is old and have multiple problems

Comment: A common practice with react-router is to maintain a separate JS file to keep all the urls in an object: `{homepage: '/home', account: '/account'}` and so on. This way, all your urls stay at one place and you can import this file wherever you want and you can call a path using its key.

Comment: @xyres the problem is that I have tons of nested routes including abstract routes and with this way I cannot access nested routes easily

Answer (score 1):

The [Navigation router](https://grahammendick.github.io/navigation/) takes named routes to the next level. You can pass strongly-typed data and often [don’t even need to know the name of the route](https://grahammendick.github.io/navigation/documentation/reusable-components.html)